# send php value without using form or session?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, session

is there a way for me to send a $_POST value to another page without using FORM or SESSION method? because the form method is already being use inside the page itself but i need to send 1 variable to the other page for confirmation.

a simple  php or javascript will be great!

this is the value

```
<input name="sig"  id="sig" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["sig"]; ?>" />
```

code that is supposed to catch the code on the next page

```
<?php
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$password = "service2012";  // Modify Password to suit for access, Max 10 Char.
if ( $pass != $password) {
    header("Location: https://www.login.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: Use AJAX or redesign your application

Comment: redisign is not an option because the value i'm planning to send to the other page is a password to open it otherwise the user will be sent back to the log-in page or get stuck to the current page he is in.

Comment: isn't that the purpose of a login page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are passing a password to the other page, then it does not make sense using `GET` values. All the solutions till now have been `GET` values, which anyone can modify. It is usually not safe and creates an [XSS vector](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet).

I want to understand why do you want to pass the password to the next page, cause usually, you design your application such that the user enters the password once, and you create a SESSION variable.

You then check this SESSION on each page that requires the user to be logged in. You can use any popular programming language to understand how to create SESSIONS. For PHP :

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['page'] = 'SomePage'; // store session data
echo "Page = ". $_SESSION['page']; //retrieve data
?>
```

You should ideally, create a session and then pass this session variable in place of passing `POST` data.

Let me know in case you need further clarification on this.

Comment: well his password is hardcoded in submit page, and I guess without database interaction there is slim chance of XSS Invasion. I dont think he is much concerned about security issue in this stage of his expertise. But however, its good to use some security measure in an application. But still the session alone is not safe. +1 for the solution

Comment: True that, I just thought I should sprinkle some XSS magic dust so that he at least knows about this :D Thank you for the upvote.

Comment: @telexper i think you don't want to pass using session and post method

Answer (score 3):

yes send it via javascript

**EDIT:**

```
<script>
function sendval(){
  var d=document.getElementById("password").value;
  document.location.href='otherpage.php?password='+d;
}
</script>
```

your **otherpage.php**

```
<?php 
$pass = $_GET['password']; 
$password = "service2012"; // Modify Password to suit for access, Max 10 Char. 
if ( $pass != $password) { 
    header("Location: login.html";); 
} 
?>
```

This is rough code,

you can call the function however you feel like.

Also you can use ajax to send the variables.

Comment: how should i run it on the other page ? still $_POST['pass']  ?

Comment: @telexper, you could use $_GET["pass"];

Comment: actually, it would be `$_GET['val']` in this example. ;)

Comment: @telexper, also if you explain what you are intending to do more briefly, may be we can suggest other good alternatives as well

Comment: i already used the form in the page, it is supposed to be the final page, then the user will be prompted to the thank you page, so the last value that is the password will be used to unlock that page. or else the user will be redirected to the login page or get stucked on the current page he is in

Comment: <input name="sig"  id="sig" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["sig"]; ?>" />

Comment: @telexper, you can use multiple forms in one page, or you can use my solution. Call the function `sendval()` it goes to other page, you can check the value in other page if correct you can do whatever you like if not kick user back to previous page or login page

Comment: @telexper, `<input name="sig" id="sig" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["sig"]; ?>" />` is this what you want to send to another page?

Comment: yes the code that will catch it is <?php
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$password = "service2012";  // Modify Password to suit for access, Max 10 Char.
if ( $pass != $password) {
    header("Location: https://www.login.html");
}
?>

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send some important data like password than i will highly recommand you to use POST method and if you don't want to do so  use

```
<form action="main.php" method="GET">
$pass = $_GET['password'];
$password = "service2012";  // Modify Password to suit for access, Max 10 Char.
if ( $pass != $password) {
    header("Location: https://www.login.html");
}//this is insecure method
```

use a link like

```
http:/website.com/main.php?data=1

//data is variable which you want to send
```

and in main.php

```
$data=$_GET['data'] ;
```

you can simply get data using global `$_GET` array

create a simple link `<a href="main.php?data=1">link</a>` or you can use `onclick="main.php?data=1"`

Comment: see the edited answer and use a simple  `$_GET['data']` in main.php to get the data

Comment: well i guess he has to pass the form field variable to another page, so he can't do like this in href attribute. For this he needs to call a function, fetch form field value and send it to another page.

Comment: which value you want to pass?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed your variable in `URL` like this
Edit:

`www.server.com/abc.php?variable=value`;

In abc.php page you will get the value.